# Connecting the visual code with the calculation code. PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt4

So I have been working on these both codes. I was wondering how can I connect them both. When both combo box choose a letter, the **second** **part** does the calculation and it gives the result in the label box. Thank You.

```
import sys
import heapq
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Dis(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dis, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel("Distance", self)
        pushbutton = QtGui.QPushButton("Find", self)

        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem("a")
        combo.addItem("b")
        combo.addItem("w")
        combo.addItem("x")
        combo.addItem("y")
        combo.addItem("z")

        combo2 = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        combo2.addItem("a")
        combo2.addItem("b")
        combo2.addItem("w")
        combo2.addItem("x")
        combo2.addItem("y")
        combo2.addItem("z")

        pushbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 75, 23))
        pushbutton.move(50,100)
        combo2.move(125, 50)
        combo.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl.move(50, 150)

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
        combo2.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Shortest Distance')
        self.show()

    def onActivated(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dis()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

# ---------Second Part -------------------------

```
def shortestPath(start, end):
    queue,seen = [(0, start, [])], set()
    while True:
        (cost, v, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if v not in seen:
            path = path + [v]
            seen.add(v)
            if v == end:
                return cost, path
            for (next, c) in graph[v].iteritems():
                heapq.heappush(queue, (cost + c, next, path))

graph = {
   'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
   'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
   'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
   'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
   'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
   'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},
}
cost, path = shortestPath(combo, combo2)
print cost, path
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect `pushbutton` with a function doing what you want

something like:

```
 #In your main()
 dis =Dis()

 def button_clicked_example():
      #example put the text from 1 box to the other 
      dis.combo.setText(dis.combo2.GetText())

 #Call the function button_clicked_example linked to the pushbutton
 dis.connect(pushbutton, SIGNAL('clicked()'), button_clicked_example)
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, but that's how I would do it

I haven't test it (as it doesn't do much) so tell me if you have any problems

Comment: Thats the problem Im having. What do I connect it to. do I connect to the second part of the code or make a new function. Also, what about the ComboBox, how would I associate that to the pushbutton.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do when the button is clicked?

Comment: When both ComboBox have choosen a letter, pressing the button will execute the second program with the letters that was picked and find the shortest distance. Then the results will display on the label box. Im still trying to make it work.